# Looping an array in table

Tags: php, arrays, html-table

I have this code:

```
<?php

    for($i=0; $i<count($data);$i++) {
        for($j=0; $j<count($data); $j++){
            if($i == $j){
            }else{
?>
            <th><?php echo $i.",".$j ?></th>
            <th><?php echo ("$data[$i]") ?></th>
            <th><?php echo ("$data[$j]")  ?></th>
<?php 
            }
        }   
    }
?>
```

Current result:

```
0,1 12 13 0,2 12 14 1,0 12 11 1,2 12 13 2,0 13 11 2,1 13 12
```

Expected result:

```
0,1 12 13 
0,2 12 14 
1,0 12 11 
1,2 12 13 
2,0 13 11 
2,1 13 12
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please show us your array structure with the output of `print_r($data);`.

Comment: like this : Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 12 [1] => 13 [2] => 14 ) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks you've got the numbers you want being output but you want to introduce line breaks after each row. You're using the `<th>` element which is part of a table, but I don't see the other table elements. All you need is to put each table row into a `<tr>` element and wrap the whole thing in a `<table>` tag.

```
<table>
<?php

    for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
        for($j = 0; $j < count($data); $j++){
            if($i == $j){
            }else{
?>
            <tr>
                <th><?php echo $i . "," . $j ?></th>
                <th><?php echo ("$data[$i]") ?></th>
                <th><?php echo ("$data[$j]") ?></th>
            </tr>
<?php 
            }
        }   
    }
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

```
<?php foreach(array_chunk($yourArray, 4) as $curta ) { ?>
 // Your Code
<? }; ?>
```